# Proof matrix inverse exists if determinant is different from zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

In a proof of “If $\det(A)\ne 0$, then an inverse of $A$ exists” in my textbook for a Linear Algebra course, there is a step that is unclear to me:

It states following known equivalence:

$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \operatorname{adj}(A) \DeclareMathOperator{\cof}{Cof}$

And then the following equivalence is obtained from this fact:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cof(a) & \cof(d) & \cof(g) \\
    \cof(b) & \cof(e) & \cof(h) \\
    \cof(c) & \cof(f) & \cof(i) 
    \end{pmatrix} = 
    det(A)*I_3
$$

So the second factor in this last equation is $\operatorname{adj}(A)$, but I'm wondering how the matrix $A$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$

Comment: Where do you get the idea that $A$ equals $1/\det(A)$ from? The latter is simply a scalar factor.

Comment: What is asserted is that $A^{-1}$ is the product of the adjugate matrix by the *scalar* $\frac1{\det A}$.

Comment: @egreg I know it's a scalar factor, that's why I don't how we get from the first equivalence to the second one?

Comment: "And then the following equivalence is obtained from this fact:" That following equivalence isn't an equivalence at all. It's just a product of two matrices. Did you mean to put $=$ in there somewhere, and maybe something else on the other side of the $=$?

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt The matrix product is missing an equals sign: you should complete it with $=\det(A)I_3$, where $I_3$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: This is at best only an example of the $3\times3$ case, not a proof of the general case.

Comment: @egreg Ok! Thank you. I've completed the equivalence, but I'm still wondering how exactly the second equivalence can be obtained from the first? Or isn't this possible and do I maybe understand the proof wrong? I can post a picture of the complete proof from the textbook, if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the text you mention is written, but it looks like you are not following the flow of the argument.

The point is that the equality  $$A\ \text {adj}(A)=\det (A)\,I_n $$ holds for any $n\times n $ matrix $A $. So if $\det (A)\neq0$ you can divide both sides of the equality by it, to get $$A\ \frac1 {\det (A)}\text {adj}(A)=I_n.$$ So now you have that the matrix $B=\frac1 {\det (A)}\text {adj}(A)$ has the property that $AB=I $, so it is an inverse for $A $ (you also need $BA=I$; this follows automatically from $AB=I $, but requires a short proof).

The equality you wrote is the case  $n=3$, but it's not really different for other  $n $.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very clear solution.